# Sending results from random array to email php

Tags: php, arrays, email, random

I am asking for help, after hours of trying to figure this out myself.

I have the following code, which I would like to email results to email.

**Here is my code:**

```
$emailme = "myemail@somewhere.com";

$subject = "Randomly selected from array";
$headers = "From: $emailme\n";

$message = "Here is the Randomly selected from array.\n
Random text: $r_array";

$r_array=file('file.txt'); 
shuffle($r_array); 
$output = "<p><center><b>The Randomly Selected Text is:</b></p><b>" .  
$r_array[0] . "All done, echoing results.";

mail($emailme,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

So far, I am able to echo the results to screen, but am unable to send results via email.

Comment: Where is your code for sending the email?

Comment: you should also place the code you have used for sending mail

Comment: Will update with complete code now.

Comment: **$r_array** is defined somewhere before **$message**?

Comment: @v.kondratyuk You nailed it! Along with your answer and Michael's, is working now, thank you. Cheers~

Comment: Good to see you got it working. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sending an email is pretty straight forward, example:

```
<?php
$r_array=file('file.txt');   
shuffle($r_array);   

$to = "recipient@example.com";
$subject = "Random Selected Text";
$body = "<p><center><b>The Randomly Selected Text is:</b></p><b>" . $r_array[0] . "All done, echoing results.";
if (mail($to, $subject, $body)) {
  echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
} else {
   echo("<p>Message delivery failed...</p>");
 }
?>
```

Something like this should work, if not, the mail server might not be properly configured on the web server.

Comment: Thanks. I get the email, it's the actual result from the random array that is not showing in the email. I tried your code, but it's still not showing the result from $r_array[0]

Comment: Sorry Michael, my fault as stated above in another comment. Was defining $r_array before the message going out. However, your code helped me tremendously, thank you. Cheers~